# WebSQL Select with AND + OR

Tags: web-sql

Is it possible to query a websql database using both AND and OR in the same statement?

This will not work:

```
tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM people 
  WHERE name="'+name1+'" OR name="'+name2+'" 
  AND category=1', [], function (tx, results) {
```

Both these do:

```
tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM people 
 WHERE name="'+name1+'" OR name="'+name2+'", 
 [], function (tx, results) {

tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM people 
 WHERE name="'+name1+'" 
 AND category=1', [], function (tx, results) {
```

Is it not possible to achieve this or is my syntax / query incorrect?

Comment: What does the error say by the way?

Comment: @Edper I don't get one it just ignores the AND part of the query at the end. Using chrome developer tools / error console, is there anywhere else to check for errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I should have experimented more before posting, adding brackets around the OR part of the query allowed it to work:

```
tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM people 
WHERE (name="'+name1+'" OR name="'+name2+'") 
AND category=1', [], function (tx, results) {
```

Comment: Based on your solution there was no error probably in the first place. It just that it has no resulting records.

Comment: There were records to match all 3 queries in the original post, the broken query just didn't work as expected - records were found where the 2 names matched and the category was ignored. Adding the brackets has resolved it. The query itself ran fine in the SQLite addon for firefox without the brackets.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation @mao. But going to back to your solution without the bracket `name2` would be associated by AND `category=1` whereas using the bracket you will have the right `OR`, namely, `name=name1 OR name=name2` instead of `name=name1 OR  (name=name2 AND category=1)` (brackets are mine).